# Image upscaling - limit for small images

Tags: css

I'm working on a mobile layout for our site. I've encounterd an issue regarding small images, posted in our forum.
In our CSS we've set

```
width: 100%;
```

which works really well for large images, scaling them in nice. How-ever, smaller images, gets blown-up and become really large and pixelated.

Is there an easy way to prevent smaller images from being extremly upscaled?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if you can do this with just CSS alone, but I know you could use jQuery, with jQuery you can check all img and check the image width, if the width is lower than 300 pixels set the css width to 50% instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to scale images that are too wide down to 100%, while leaving smaller images alone, you will have to write `max-width:100%` instead of `width:100%`. No need to give special classes to smaller images.

Comment: Works exactly like intended. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of CSS and JS to achieve your result.

You can detect using JS your image with width, if it is larger that x and apply a CSS class for bigger images, like:

```
.bigImage {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Apply a similar rule  if yout image is under X width:

```
.smallImage {
max-width: 50%;
}
```